# Creating an image element (modifying the DOM)

Tags: jquery

I am currently taking a course on programming and am struggling with one particular question. I believe I know the answer but I would like to actually understand the concept fully.

I'm trying to figure out whether or not using this syntax (below) in jQuery is **only creating an image** or if it is **creating an image and modifying the DOM.**

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('<img>', {
    src: 'images/little-book.png',
    alt: 'New Book',
    title: 'This is a good book to read'
  });

});
```

When I test this out in the browser (I have an image in an 'images' directory to use), I receive no errors in the console but I don't see anything render either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not **trying** to actually render something. I'm trying to understand what my code above is doing explicitly.

Comment: JavaScript is a language that "clicks" after about a year.  Once you get it, you just "get it" and all the additional stuff (jQuery, NodeJS, Angular, Require, etc) just falls into place.  I'd recommend you check these out: "www.codecademy.com", "www.codeschool.com", and the publication: "Javascript Demystified" codecademy helped me get started, codeschool helped me break and fix a lot of stuff, javascript demystified screwed the lightbulb in, trial and error made it flicker, and codecademy's JS course a second time lit the bulb.  It's a long(er than you think) worthwhile road to travel down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
// ^ "$" = call to the linked jQuery.js file (This is the same as telling the 
//browser you want to use "ready" function from the jQuery you linked in your html)

$(document).ready(function(){
  // ^ "(document)" the document(DOM)

$(document).ready(function(){
          // ^ when the entire DOM is considered "ready" as all 
          // of the browser requests for resources are satisfied or
          // have received an error.

$(document).ready(function(){
                  // ^ If jQuery is loaded, and the entire DOM and resources have 
                  // been resolved, pass the following "function" (your jQuery code)
                  // back into the document for the browser to show/use. 
                  // (execute the code within once the page is ready.  This is 
                  // where your jQuery typically gets written/executed until you 
                  // separate it out and link your larger javascript file where your 
                  // jQuery functionality will reside and be linked to your html 
                  // document.
```

Below is what you're telling the browser to do with the HTML/page once the page has been fully prepared for the view.  It's ready and jQuery's been loaded and called on the dollar sign...

```
$('<img>', {   // Makes an image tag object. give the following attributes

src: 'images/little-book.png',  
// Defines the source of the image using current directory 
// i.e ("www.websiteAddress.com/IMAGES/LITTLE-BOOK.PNG)

alt: 'New Book',  
// Generates the image html element's "alt" value. 
// The plain text that displays if the image doesn't load.

title: 'This is a good book to read'  
// Gives the image tag a title of "This is a good book to read"

});
// Ends the image object. At this point it's been instantiated (exists) 
// and it is a well defined image object to create the html image tag from
```

Bhojendra's addition of ".appendTo('body');" (removing the semicolon in lieu of a dot and then replacing it at the new end of the script tells jQuery the following. Now that I have instantiated(created) this object, and I have defined it (image element, src where the image is, alt to call it when can't or won't display, and title to define what the title for it will be) I now want to append it to the "body" element.

```
});
```

Becomes:

}).appendTo('body');

^once I have finished the element object "", append it to the body element.

NOTE: Using dot notation, if you were to define the "image" element as a variable previously like this:

```
var imgToInsert =   $('<img>', {
src: 'images/little-book.png',
alt: 'New Book',
title: 'This is a good book to read'
});
```

NOTE: Your current code for your IMG could just be prefixed with "var varName = " + all your code for your IMG as well.  If you wanted to, you could now write on a separate line "$('body').append(varName);" Where "varName" is the same as what you declared your IMG variable to be named, and you can call it into the plain "append" function, which is "appendTo" in reverse.  The only benefit here being, you could then "append" any variable, not just the object you had immediately declared previously.

Here's the jQuery references, although I think they're a little hard to grasp from a newer coder's point of perception.

append: (http://api.jquery.com/append/)

appendTo: (http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code **creates a new element** but isn't appended in the DOM Tree.

You just need to append it then you'll see the modified DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('<img>', { //create new element
    src: 'images/little-book.png',
    alt: 'New Book',
    title: 'This is a good book to read'
  }).appendTo('body'); //append it to the body

});
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes):

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's .innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new `<div>` element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$( "<img />" )` or `$( "<img>" ), $( "<a></a>" ) or $( "<a>" )` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `.createElement()` function.